# C# DataTable select columns where column name like

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I would like to select all columns in a DataTable that begin with the characters 'hz'. At the moment I am doing this:

```
var uploadTable = dataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "locID", "hz1582", "hz1581", "hz1580", "hz1579", "hz1578", "hz1577", "hz1576", "hz1575", "hz1574", "hz1573", "hz1572", "hz1571");
```

However, the 'hz' columns are variable each time I run my code, so I need some way of selecting all columns in the table that begin with hz. Note also that the column 'locID' is always present and needs to be returned. So, I need something like this:

```
var uploadTable = dataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "locID", "hz%");
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: What means you need to select the columns? You need to select the rows which column-names start with `hz`? Or you need to select only the `DataColumn`s without data?

Comment: I need to select the rows as well. i.e. subset the datatable based on the coluumn names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use LINQ for this task:

```
DataTable uploadtable = dataTable.Copy();
var removeColumns = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
   .Where(c => !c.ColumnName.StartsWith("hz", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

foreach (DataColumn colToRemove in removeColumns)
    uploadtable.Columns.Remove(colToRemove.ColumnName);
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like just what I need!

Answer (score 1):

```
 string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                         .Select(x => x.ColumnName).Where(n => n.Contains("hz")).ToArray();

    var uploadTable = dataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(false, columnNames);
```

Comment: you linq will not work for _**Machzor**_ column name?

Comment: @J.SMTBCJ15 why?

Comment: because @azar  he said start with not contains and if column name is Machzor will be considered as column which is not actually

Comment: @J.SMTBCJ15 Yes Thanks